# Php mysql issue with mysql query and functions

Tags: php, mysql, function

I habe a database with some informations and want to print them on my website. So to do that, I want to create for each info a "the"-function, show:

```
$profileMeta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE profileID = '$profileID' ");

    while($meta = mysql_fetch_array($profileMeta)) {

        //Variablen festlegen
        $profileID = $meta['profileID'];
        $profileName = $meta['profileName'];
        $slogan = $meta['slogan'];
    }

    //THE - Funktionen

    //profileID
    function theProfileID() {
        echo $profileID;
    }

    //profileName
    function theProfileName() {
        echo $profileName;
    }
```

I include this request in my profile.php-File.
But when I want to print the profileName with "`<?php theProfileName(); ?>`" it doesn't work :(

But why? I can't find the issue...

Thanks for any help.

Sorry for english mistakes, I'm from Germany.

Comment: It's a scope issue - `$profileName` is a local variable in the function, and it's not set anywhere.

Comment: Function variable scope is the issue.  You are definining $profileID outside of the function so you need to add global $profileID; above the echo and it'll work

Comment: Or to send profile name as argument in function...

Comment: Probably better than doing it as a global tbh :)

Comment: Thanks, it works with `$GLOBALS["companyName"];` :)

Comment: On a side note: If you are writing new code you should refrain from using the `mysql_*` functions, they are in the process of becoming deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO objects instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
$profileMeta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE profileID = '$profileID' ");

while($meta = mysql_fetch_array($profileMeta)) {

    //Variablen festlegen
    $profileID = $meta['profileID'];
    $profileName = $meta['profileName'];
    $slogan = $meta['slogan'];
}

//THE - Funktionen

//profileID
function theProfileID() {
global $profileID;     //Global
    echo $profileID;
}

//profileName
function theProfileName() {
global $profileName;     //////Global
    echo $profileName;
}
```

Comment: Technically correct, personally I'd prefer it to have only a single variable global (e.g. $meta) and have the function return the index of the array: `function theProfileID() { global $meta; echo $meta['profileID']; }`